# SQL Server : split value based on delimiter and match at run-time

Tags: sql-server, split

I have 2 simplified tables (all columns are `varchar`). Some rows in `T1_TAB` for F2 contain multiple values separated by `;`, some do not have separators at all as shown below (sometimes `;` might also appear at the beginning and/or at the end). F2 in `T2_TAB` always has a single value.

I need to be able to pull rows from ether table based on single selection from one table and likeliness on F2 columns.

T1_TAB

```
F0   |  F2
--------------
1          ;30
2       ;10;20;30
3          ;20;30;
4          10
```

T2_TAB

```
F1   |  F2
-------------
100       10    
200       20      
300       30
```

I can do:

```
SELECT T1.F0
FROM T1_TAB T1 
LEFT JOIN T2_TAB T2
ON T2.F2 LIKE '%' + T1.F2 + '%'
WHERE T2.F1 = '200'
```

This would bare result:

```
2
3
```

Now, I need to do the opposite. For instance:

Based on condition `WHERE T1.F0 = 3`, I need to pull from T2 rows with F1 equals 200 and 300 respectively. I guess I need to somehow split ;20;30; by a ";" and do the loop to match each value separately at run-time disregarding blank tokens.

Comment: Are you able to normalize your table?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I cannot manipulate tables. This is given. Thanks.

Comment: That's also not really a delimited value in your T1_TAB.F2 column, as you sometimes have a leading delimiter, and sometimes don't. There are split functions available on the internets, but if you have the option I'd do as njk suggests and normalize your data. Using split functions in TSQL generally doesn't work out well in the end, but they can be useful for taking data like you have and putting it into a normalized table structure.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask instead how you can normalize your tables!

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I'm a user, who does not have rights to restructure tables - just pulling data for analyses. I'll try to search for splitters... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function which converts the semicolon-separated string into a table of values:

```
create function CreateTableFromList(@Values varchar(1000))
returns @table table (id int)
as
begin
declare @p int = 1, @q int = 1, @n int = len(@Values)

while @p<@n begin
  set @q = CHARINDEX(';',@Values,@p)
  if @q=0 set @q=@n + 1
  if @q > @p 
    insert into @table values (cast(substring(@Values,@p,@q-@p) as int))
  set @p= @q + 1
end
return
end
```

and then

```
select T2.F1 
  from T2
where T2.F2 in (
  select ID 
    from T1 
         cross apply dbo.CreateTableFromList(T1.F2) 
  where T1.F0=3
  )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thanks alzaimar.