# Split column with delimited values for an inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to perform an inner join to a column containing delimited values like:

```
123;124;125;12;3433;35343;
```

Now what I am currently doing is this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetFruitDetails]
(
    @CrateID int
)
AS

SELECT Fruits.*, Fruits_Crates.CrateID 
    FROM Fruits_Crates INNER JOIN Fruits 
    ON Fruits_Crates.FruitID = Fruits.ID
    WHERE Fruits_Crates.CrateID = @CrateID
```

Now the issue is I am saving the data this way:

```
FruitCrateID  FruitID 
1             1;
2             1;2;3;4
3             3;
```

How can I inner join `FruitsIDs` to the fruit table to get fruit details as well?

Comment: The actual problem is that you store multiple values in a single column which you should never do. Can you cnahge you table design?

Comment: @juergend yes I can, but then I have another problem which is described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869110/stored-procedure-insert-multiple-rows

Comment: You can try something like ... @multi_value LIKE '%;'+FruitID+';%'. For parentheses you can add combinations '(%'+... or simply get values in other format e.g. ";123;124;125;12;". However, it is better to change DB design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server : split value based on delimiter and match at run-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418005/sql-server-split-value-based-on-delimiter-and-match-at-run-time)

Comment: @CustomizedName The answer in the post I flagged as duplicate should work for you, although changing the design as _juergen d_ suggested might be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method posted in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755165/inserting-values-in-to-a-table-from-a-comma-separated-string/26755587#26755587)**, you can convert the delimited string into rows of a temp table and then join to that:

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e6d2/3)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Fruits_Crates
    ([FruitCrateID] int, [FruitID] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Fruits_Crates
    ([FruitCrateID], [FruitID])
VALUES
    (1, '1;'),
    (2, '1;2;3;4;'),
    (3, '3;')
;

CREATE TABLE Fruits
    ([FruitID] int, [FruitName] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Fruits
    ([FruitID], [FruitName])
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple'),
    (2, 'Banana'),
    (3, 'Orange'),
    (4, 'Pear')
;
```

**Insert to temp table**:

```
 SELECT A.[FruitCrateID],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS FruitId  
 INTO #fruits
 FROM  (SELECT [FruitCrateID],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([FruitID], ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  Fruits_Crates) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**Join temp table to lookup**:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.FruitName
FROM #Fruits t1
INNER JOIN Fruits t2 on t1.FruitId = t2.FruitId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e6d2/3/1)**:

```
| FRUITCRATEID | FRUITID | FRUITNAME |
|--------------|---------|-----------|
|            1 |       1 |     Apple |
|            2 |       1 |     Apple |
|            2 |       2 |    Banana |
|            2 |       3 |    Orange |
|            2 |       4 |      Pear |
|            3 |       3 |    Orange |
```

Comment: I am going to try changing database design and then using c# table valued parameter instead, but I think your answer is right too, thank you :)

Comment: @CustomizedName yeah, changing the design is the correct thing to do.